# "undefined" error appear when append?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I define var like below :

```
var k, k1 ="";
k += '<li><a>'+data+'</a></li>';
k1 += '<li><a>'+data+'</a></li>';
```

and append like :

```
a("ul#foo4", d.$me).append(k);   
a("ul#foo5", d.$me).append(k1);
```

I receive an error is "undefined" with data is appended from var k, k1 is ok.

On the other hand, if i define var like :

`var k =""; var k1 ="";` the "undefined" error is solved.

Say me reasons why?

Comment: @all : thanks for your help, I may misunderstand two ways of define var. Solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't define `k=""`.

Define both `k` and `k1` as emty:

```
var k = "";
var k1 = "";
```

Then it should work.

Comment: downvoted? Why? Maybe downvoter will describe reason?

Comment: My answer was upvoted four times and downvoted three times.  That's Stack Overflow, kid.

Comment: @zur4ik, Accipheran : i don't know why they vote down all of answers, not me.

Comment: I got `+5` and `-2`. Somebody is just playing. It's just vandalism.

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialize variable k with some value before appending a string to it.

**k** remains undefined until you initialize it.

So when you initialize `var k="";` , it solves all the problem.

I hope you got the reason.

Answer (score 3):

In your first line you're not setting a value for `k`.  Do `var k = "" ; var k1 = "";` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Because after the line

```
var k, k1 = ""
```

`k` will be `undefined` and `k1` will be `""`. That's not an error, that's just how javascript works.

`undefined.append` then yields an error

The solution is to write

```
var k = "";
var k1 = "";
```

like you mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

In javascript & jquery to define more than 1 variable define each variable at that time
like..

```
var k="", k1=""; 
otherwise 
var k, k1 ="";
in this case it will create the variable k but with no value...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare multiple variables with the same var keyword as mentioned in below:

```
 var k,k1;
```